# Change row height based on text in cells

Tags: vba, ms-word

Trying to create a macro in word, based on two tables, but im really stuck and don't know how to fix it

[image]

Basically want the rows of the first table to change whether based on the letter in the column of table 2.

```
Sub TableAdjust()
Dim aCell As Cell
Dim x As Long

With Documents("Document1")

For Each aCell In .Tables(2).Rows(1).Cells
If aCell.Range.Text = "A" Then
x = aCell.ColumnIndex
.Tables(1).Rows(x).SetHeight RowHeight:=InchesToPoints(3), _
 HeightRule:=wdRowHeightExactly

ElseIf aCell.Range.Text = "B" Then
x = aCell.ColumnIndex
.Tables(1).Rows(x).SetHeight RowHeight:=InchesToPoints(0.4), _
 HeightRule:=wdRowHeightExactly
 
Else

MsgBox "Error"

End If


Next aCell

End With
End Sub
```

Can anyone help, would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table cells don't just contain the text that you can see. They always have an end cell character. (You can see these non-printing characters by clicking the Show/Hide [image] button on the Home tab).  So `If aCell.Range.Text = "A"` will never evaluate to true.

You can solve this simply by using the `Left` function to check just the first character in the range.

```
Sub TableAdjust()
  Dim aCell As Cell
  Dim x As Long

  With Documents("Document1")

    For Each aCell In .Tables(2).Rows(1).Cells
      x = aCell.ColumnIndex
      Select Case Left(aCell.Range.Text, 1)
        Case "A"
          .Tables(1).Rows(x).SetHeight RowHeight:=InchesToPoints(3), _
            HeightRule:=wdRowHeightExactly

        Case "B"
          .Tables(1).Rows(x).SetHeight RowHeight:=InchesToPoints(0.4), _
            HeightRule:=wdRowHeightExactly
 
        Case Else

          MsgBox "Error"

      End Select

    Next aCell

  End With
End Sub
```